# What's a line for black in the Sicilian that has good piece activity?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

I'm looking to learn the Sicilian for black.  There seem to be a hundred different variations.  It's easy enough to look them up, but it's hard to get a feel for what kind of games they lead to.

Can anyone recommend a line in the Sicilian that leads to somewhat open positions, with lots of piece activity, and doesn't tend to lead to lots of trades?

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, the Najdorf and Sveshnikov are probably the best, as far as getting an active game while being objectively sound. Another option is the Dragon, which is often even sharper (while somehow having less theory than the aforementioned two). However, the downside is that objectively, White should be pressing a little. The Dragon's still in better theoretical standing than a number of other Sicilians though, it's just not quite on the level of the Najdorf and Sveshnikov.